# NASM disassembled code different from assembled

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have this code being NASM assembled (setting segment selectors for protected mode but irrelevant for this question):

```
bits 16
.....
bits 32
mov ax, 00010000b
mov ds, ax
mov ax, 00011000b
mov es, ax
```

The NASM disassembly shows that machine code sees it as:

```
66B810008ED8 mov eax,0xd88e0010
66B818008EC0 mov eax,0xc08e0018
```

This is clearly one heck of an assembly job. Could someone elucidate what goes wrong here? Is this a bug?[image: picture of code and disassembly next to each other]

I also noticed mov edi, 0 doesn't get prefixed with 0x66 even though it is after bits 32 directive but NASM leaves 32 bits after the opcode.

Comment: Are you using NDISASM to dump this?

Comment: Pure guess, but it looks to me like it's assembling 16-bit mode code, but disassembling as 32-bit mode code. Thus it expects a larger constant to move into the larger register, and basically interprets the register move instruction as part of the constant.

Comment: What you may wish to do is use NASM to output the encodings. Add `-l boot.lst` to your NASM command line to generate a listing file called boot.lst. I'm guessing you are using NDISASM or some similar tool. NDISASM (or similar tool) is unaware that there is a mixture of 32-bit and 16-bit code and doesn't know to change the decoding

Comment: Yes, it's ndisasm.

Comment: But it disassembled other 16 and 32 bit commands correctly.

Comment: Some of the output may look right but it was still disassembled improperly. I'm assuming you disassembled with `-b32` to get this output. Trust me when I say this. Binary files that are output lose all information about what type of encoding (16/32/64 bit) were used. The only way to get the 32-bit code disassembled properly with NDISASM is to skip over the 16-bit code by specifying the number of bytes to skip with the `-k` option and specify `-b32` to decode as 32-bit.

Comment: NASM isn't the problem here, NDISASM is. It isn't a bug with NDISASM either because it is up to yoo to tell NDISASM where the 32-bit code starts and to decode it as 32-bit. NDISASM can't do it automatically.

Comment: But CPU knows where to start executing 32 bit code? As in that's what it defaults to once in protected mode? What opcode exactly triggers CPU to start executing code 32 bit?

Comment: the CPU doesn't know anything, it has a state, and at every machine cycle it does modify its state according to the previous and content of memory (i.e. what instruction it reads from memory pointed at by `ip` register, and if that instruction references other memory, then what values are found there). If it did run over instructions switching the CPU into 32 bit mode, then it will further decode and execute memory bytes as 32 bit mode instructions, but if it is still in 16b mode, it will decode and execute the same bytes as 16 bit mode instructions = you will get completely different results.

Comment: But yes, once you switch to "32b protected mode", the further instructions are decoded+executed in 32 bit mode, but I can't recall from head how the switch to protected mode from 16b is done (at which instruction), check some commented listing of advanced bootloader which does switch to 32b mode for details how to enter 32b mode (it's lot of tedious details you normally don't need to memorize, because modern OS+bootloader does this stuff for you ... unless you are trying to write your own bootloader... but that's not interesting topic for me, so somebody else will provide better hints)

Comment: @MichaelPetch so this still is a problem. I disassembled it as 32 bit code and now mov ds,ax disassembled and mov ds,eax. This would cause the reboot because moving 32 bits into 16 bits is all kinds of wrong.

Comment: This is reallyan X-Y problem. You are trying to really track a problem that causes a reboot. Did you try any of the code I provided in my previous answer? Did they fail?

Comment: You should create a new question. Post your complete code and say where you think it reboots.

Comment: Once using 32-bit encoding you don't use prefixes as the processor will be executing with 32-bit data and addresses by default. That is what will happen when you do the FAR JMP using 32-bit code descriptor in the GDT. The processor literally changes its defaults.

Comment: I should point something out. NASM does some optimizations under the hood. In 32-bit code it converts a mov from a 16-bit register to a segment register to a mov using the 32-bit register. That saves a byte in the code and does the same thing. If you do `mov ds, ax` it actually encodes `mov ds, eax`.

Comment: If you want to turn off such optimizations you can pass the `-O0` option to NASM.

Comment: You should just add your entire code to this question.Taking screenshots of it isn't very useful. We'd probably be able to tell you why the code doesn't work.

Comment: One other thing.When the processor is in 32-bit protected mode the instruction prefixes pretty much have the reverse meaning.They will override the 32-bit operands with 16-bit ones. Effectively the reverse of what happens when in 16-bit real mode which overrides 16-bit ones with 32-bit ones.

Comment: 8E MOV Sreg r/m16. But ndisasm shows eax, which is r/m32

Comment: See my comment earlier. NASM performs some optimization. It took `mov ds, ax` and actually output `mov ds,eax`. As I said before you can override that by passing `-O0` to NASM. The reason NASM does that is because in 32-bit code `MOV DS, AX` takes 3 bytes encoded as  `668ED8`where as `MOV DS, EAX` would be encoded `8ED8` .NASM simply used an encoding that was cheaper space wise but does the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave optimization on.